# Error when accessing a processed file

Tags: file, exception, file-io, streamwriter

I am facing a problem. In my program, I create a file on the desktop:

```
        var desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        var fullFileName = Path.Combine(desktopFolder, "Report.txt");
        var fs = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Create);

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
```

[...writing to file...]

```
        sw.WriteLine("Report generated with***.");
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
```

and later on, after the file is completed, I am reading it again:

```
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fullFileName);
        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(fi.OpenRead());
        string sLine = "";
        while (sLine != null)
        {
            sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
            if (sLine != null)
            {
                Report.Items.Add(sLine);
            }
        }
```

The thing is, if I try to read the file twice, I get an error :The process cannot access the file, because it is being used by another process. Any ideas what might be wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by not properly calling the `Close()` method on the `StreamWriter` before attempting to open or access the file with the `StreamReader`. Going off of the snippet in your post, you would want to make the following call after writing everything you want to the file with the `StreamWriter`.

```
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out - I actually do call a close, I have added those commands in my original post. I never seem to know which parts of the code I need to post. :-D Anyway, It gives me that error when reading the second time, the first one goes through smoothly...

Comment: When you say 'read the file twice' do you mean two iterations of the loop or are you actually creating another instance of `StreamReader` and passing in the file stream again.

Comment: I am creating it all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for working with file

```
using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(/* your arguments here *\)) {
    // code that uses it here
}
// file is closed here
```